# Div with link disappears before I can use it (jquery hide/show)

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have an icon that displays a div with a link when I hover over it. A user should be able to click this link but it disappears when the mouse is away form the icon. Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening?

The code:

```
$('.div1').hover(function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().show('fast');
},
function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();    
    $(this).next().hide('fast');
});
```

I made a JSfiddle to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/2wrjG/5

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.domaininfo').hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().show('fast');
},
function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.domain-info-window').hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).hide('fast');
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2wrjG/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you leave the img-tag when you try to click the link. I would suggest to wrap everything and call the hover on this wrap.

Here a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wrjG/2/

```
$('.wrapper').hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('a').show('fast');
},

function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('a').hide('fast');
});
```

HTML-Part:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="domaininfo" src="http://domeinwinkel.sitestatus.nl/gfx/itje.png">
<a class="domain-info-window" id="domain-info-window-2" href="#">
Is deze domeinnaam bij een andere provider geregistreerd maar wil je profiteren van de voordelen van Domeinwinkel? Verhuizen naar Domeinwinkel is snel geregeld!
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.domaininfo {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the div is shown when you hover over the image.
if you want the link to disappear only when you have clicked on it i guess this could help you.

```
enter code here

 $('.domaininfo').hover(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          $(this).next().show('fast');
    },function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.domain-info-window').click(function (e) {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
```